# The u* rate for M/M/2 queue to have same "average waiting time in queue of a customer" with M/M/1 system with rate u

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

Ok here is the question, in a supermarket I have one cashier with u and a single M/M/1 queue,
Suppose I want to get 2 cashier with same rate u*.What would should be the u* value for me to have same" average waiting time in queue of a customer" with the situation 1. 
I looked the W formulas from "Bertsekas, Gallager Data Networks" book, however equating Respective W s of M/M/1 and M/M/2 and getting an ratio between u and u* is far beyond my math skills. 
Thank you for your help!
u=service rate

Comment: What is $u$? That will help us to know.

Comment: It is "service rate" (inverse of average service time)

Comment: It's standard to use $\mu$ (mu) not $u$.